# Implementing paging an API in AWS using lambda and python language

Tags: python, aws-lambda, paging

I am creating an API in AWS using lambda. The database is snowflakes.
To retrieve data, I need to pass in parameters below for the query

```
        a. accountNumber
        b. startTime
        c. endTime
        d. page
```

From postman, I want to be able to pass in a page number and my json response
will have the data for the specific page.

Here is a sample of what the json response will look like.

```
        {
          "total": 400,
          "totalPages" : 4,
          "page": 2,
          'transactions": [
              {
            "accountNumber": "1234",
                "amount": "1234",
                "description": "1234",  
              },
              {
            "accountNumber": "1234",
                "amount": "1234",
                "description": "1234",  
              }
              ...
           ]
        }
```

I want to display 100 records in a page. I am not clear on how to go about this.
I don't think there is anything like session. I am using python as a programming language.

I need some steps on hom to go about this. Can the query be smart enough to know where it stopped
and the next data to return?

I have not done this before but tried to google and no luck yet.

Comment: You appear to be asking how to do pagination with an ephemeral backend (AWS Lambda) and a SQL-like database (Snowflake). Here are some [ideas](https://dev.to/pragativerma18/unlocking-the-power-of-api-pagination-best-practices-and-strategies-4b49). Fundamentally, the client is going to need to know what to request (based on prior responses from the backend) because the backend isn't persistent.